# c# to create direct membership rules for SCCM 2012

Tags: c#, wmi, sccm

I am trying to build a C# application offering most common SCCM 2012 functions used by our 1st level support teams globally.

Therefore one of the most important function is to add computers (resourceIDs) to a collection as a DirectMembershipRule.

I have already done the similar things with Powershell and also created a GUI. But as multithreating and also the GUI makes the "script" more and more unstable I would like to continue with a DotNet application.
Unfortuantely I am not experienced at all in C#. Altough I could already manage to read from our SQL database and gather already collection names, computers of a collection and others.

Adding to a collection seems to happen most reliable through WMI method and there I got stuck completely. I managed to receive WMI data like Bios Info or Disk info from our server but was not able to trigger methods creating a new instance for a Membership rule.

I would be very happy to get some help here.
:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to be found but if you look at [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc143628.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) there is a second part starting with the comment "Add to All System collection." That basically explains this. What you need for this to work is two dlls from the folder of the System Center Configuration Manager Console, AdminUI.WQLQueryengine.dll and Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Managementprovider.dll . With those you can basically write code almost exactly like the many WMI examples for VBS that can be found. It would look something like this:

```
using Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider;
using Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine;

 SmsNamedValuesDictionary namedValues = new SmsNamedValuesDictionary();
 using (WqlConnectionManager connection = new WqlConnectionManager(namedValues)) {
    connection.Connect("<site server>");
    IResultObject collection = connection.GetInstance("SMS_Collection.collectionId='<CollectionID>'");

    IResultObject collectionRule = connection.CreateEmbeddedObjectInstance("SMS_CollectionRuleDirect");
    collectionRule["ResourceClassName"].StringValue = "SMS_R_System";
    collectionRule["ResourceID"].IntegerValue = <ResourceID>;

    Dictionary<string, object> inParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    inParams.Add("collectionRule", collectionRule);
    collection.ExecuteMethod("AddMembershipRule", inParams);
}
```

Imo this should basically also be doable with "normal" WMI calls without the help of those dlls but as this is how it is done in the MS examples I always assumed some kind of advantage and did it this way.

Comment: Thank you for this fast and really helpful hint :-)